# C Looping a switch using Y/N options. Choosing N doesn't close the program

Tags: c++, c, loops, switch-statement, case

I've only started coding C. (freshman here, no experience, only basic html)
For some reason, whenever I choose the option 'N', it just creates a new line.

At my second `scanf` whenever I change my `'%s'`, the result changes. 
When I use, `"%d"`,after entering a number, it continuously enter "`Choose a number between 1-4`". If I use `"%c"`,after entering a number, it will skip directly to the loop. Help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, ok = 0;
    char input;
    while (ok == 0)
    {
          printf("Choose a number between 1-4\n");
          scanf("%d", &n);
          switch (n)
          {
                 case 1:
                      printf("You've chosen number 1");
                      break;
                 case 2:
                      printf("You've chosen number 2");
                      break;
                 case 3:
                      printf("You've chosen number 3");
                      break;
                 case 4:
                      printf("You've chosen number 4");
                      break;
                 default:
                         printf("You have chosen an invalid number");
          }
          printf("\nInput again? (Y/N)\n");
          scanf("%s", &input);
          if (input=='n'||input=='N')
          {ok++;}
          else if (input=='Y'||input=='y')
          {printf("\n");}


    }

 getchar();
 getchar();   
}
```

Comment: Why no `iostream`'s [`std::cin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/)? It's easier to use.

Comment: `scanf("%d"` does not remove the newline (what corresponds to you pressing Enter) from the stream. Your subsequent `scanf` reads it.

To detect this you could check the result of `scanf("%s"` and also check what you received (other than just comparing vs. YyNn). To prevent it you need to discard the rest of the line after the `%d` was input successfully.

Comment: Not related to you problem, but your code is not very elegant. How would write this code if the number to be chosen is between 1 and 100 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
scanf("%s", &input);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c", &input);
```

and get rid of `getchar()`s at the end. It will work as you wanted. `%c` specifier reads a char character, but it does not omit whitespace characters. Putting space onto scanf's format will deal with whitespaces and read first non-whitespace char. To be more clear, see what man page says about `%c` format specifier:

> (...) The usual skip of  leading white  space  is  suppressed. To skip
>   white space first, use an explicit space in the format.

However, if you are really learning C++, stick with cin/cout, rather than scanf/printf's.

Here's how your program would look like if you would replace printf/scanf with cin/cout. If you've done that previously, you wouldn't had that kind of trouble.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, ok = 0;
    char input;
    while (!ok)
    {
        cout << "Choose a number between 1-4\n";
        cin >> n;

        switch (n)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "You've chosen number 1";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "You've chosen number 2";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "You've chosen number 3";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "You've chosen number 4";
                break;
            default:
                cout << "You have chosen an invalid number";
        }
        cout << "\nInput again? (Y/N)\n";
        cin >> input;

        if (input=='n' || input=='N')
        {
            ok++;
        }
        else if (input=='Y' || input=='y')
        {
            cout << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then we should add the [tag:c++] tag again?

Comment: Well, I really don't know. I too think that question is C-only, but if OP really wants to learn C++, then he should know that what he had posted is pure C. I showed how he could achieve what he wants using C++'s I/O.

Comment: It actually didn't work though, using `%c`, whenever I enter the number, it posts "You've chosen number 'x', Input again? (Y/N), Choose a number between 1-4." Oops, crap, we doing C. But still, thanks for the answer!

Comment: If it didn't work, please be more clear how exactly it should work. Remember that format should be `" %c"`, not `"%c"` (notice the space before percentage sign).

Comment: @macfij oops, didn't notice it should be `' %c'`. It finally worked. Thank you! Another question, what is the a difference between `"%c"` and `" %c"'

Comment: @Xeganthy if my answer helped, consider marking it as accepted. Re-read my answer again, there's some description why space is needed. Usually, scanf omits signs such as spaces, tabs and newlines, but not for %c.