# using printf( ) twice in a C program

Tags: c

I just started learning C and one of my assignment is asking me to ask user enter a character twice. Each time user enters a character, the program will give user a response. The problem I am having right now is that every time the user enters a character, the program stops to proceed to the next question. Can someone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{      
    char reply,reply2;

    printf("Are you an engineering major (Y/N)? ");
    scanf("%c",&reply);

    if (reply == 'y' || reply =='Y')
    {
        printf("Hey, you're an engineering major");
    }
    if (reply == 'n' || reply == 'N')
    {
        printf("You are not an engineering major");
    }

    printf("Are you a freshman (Y/N)?");
    scanf("%c",&reply2);

    if (reply2 == 'y' || reply2 =='Y')
    {
        printf("Hey, you're a freshman");
    }
    if (reply2 == 'n' || reply2 == 'N')
    {
        printf("You are not a freshman");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) -and of every function that you are using. You need to test the result of `scanf`. You should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and you should **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the problem is a trap that a lot of newbies fall into: none of your printed strings have a newline. You need to add `\n` to the end of your strings, as in `printf("You are not a freshman\n");`

The reason is that typically `stdout` (the stream where `printf` writes its text to) is *line buffered*. This means that it buffers all text until it either sees a newline or is forced to flush its contents via `fflush`. Only then the text that was buffered up to this point appears on screen.

**Edit:** Your second problem is that the `scanf` format `"%c"` reads *any* character. (I'm not sure whether it's line buffered as well, but its behaviour looks a bit like it.) Your first call `scanf("%c",&reply)` reads the `y` or `n` character but leaves the newline from pressing enter still in the stream. Your second call `scanf("%c",&reply2)` then reads the newline which was still in the stream (you can see that by doing a `printf("%d\n", reply2);` which will print `10`). To fix that, use the format string `" %c"` (notice the space!) which tells `scanf` to ignore whitespace.

Also, you should handle unexpected input:

```
if (reply == 'y' || reply =='Y')
{
    printf("Hey, you're an engineering major.\n");
}
else if (reply == 'n' || reply == 'N')
{
    printf("You are not an engineering major.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("I don't understand the answer '%c'.\n", reply);
}
```

(Exercise: implement that logic using `switch` instead of `if/else if/else` ;-)

Comment: I just added "\n" for all my strings, however the program still exits after the second question appears.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that you're only reading one character with the first scanf call, but in order to input this you would have to type y or n, and then press enter. 
The enter is registered as another character on the input stream, a newline, but because the first scanf call reads only one character its still in the stream when it is called for the second time. This leads to reply2 = '\n', skipping your if statements and terminating the program.

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there a way that I can assign variable to "reply2" without using one printf()?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `\n` at the end of your `printf`s to make your output more cleaner and understandable.Also add a space before the `%c` in the second `scanf`.This is done because scanf does not consume the `\n` character after you enter the first character.As the Enter key
(`\n`) is also a character,it gets consumed by the second `scanf`.The space before the `%c` will
discard all blanks like spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
scanf("%c",&reply2);
```

to

```
scanf(" %c",&reply2);
```

This will tell scanf to skip all the whitespace characters and read the first non-whitespace char. Otherwise, there will be a newline character `\n` read onto the reply2 variable. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710062/c-looping-a-switch-using-y-n-options-choosing-n-doesnt-close-the-program/25710285#25710285).